# vscode multi-root workspace root folder names

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the root folder names of a workspace other than editing `workspace.json` manually with the specific name?
I have a workspace like this:

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "/Users/***/dev/x/src"
        },
        {
            "path": "/Users/***/dev/y/src"
        },
        {
            "path": "/Users/***/dev/z/src"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

They look like this:

[image]

I know I can add the `name` property to each of those. But I'm always adding and removing folders from there, is there a way to display the full path or a couple of extra levels as default? or is there any other way to update the name of the folder programmatically on adding a folder to the workspace?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a feature. See docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-file-schema. You'll probably just have to accept having to manually specify the name field.